# BlueHost vs. VNhosting for Drupal

Tags: drupal, hosting

I'm dropping Godaddy, and moving my drupal websites to a new host. The word seems to be that bluehost and VNhosting architecture is best suited for MySQL intense Drupal. I've heard a lot of people on the drupal forums say that VNhosting is faster than Bluehost, almost unanimously.

After some investigating, I learned that VNhosting doesn't allow PHP to access more than 32MB of RAM? How can this be? I've had sites with almost no traffic, and a medium amount of modules (30-40) crash with a PHP memory error.

Can anyone share their experience with ANhosting.com hosting Drupal sites?

Thanks,

cinqotimo

Comment: Suggest moving to serverfault, not development related.

Comment: I want to talk to drupal developers, not server admins....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32mb is a pretty standard level for a shared account type account. If i were you i would look into getting a VPS or dedicated box that way you are in control. Linode for example is great and pretty cheap - although i suppose cheap is a relative term. I expect to pay ~$240+ anually for a hosted server to run 1-2 sites on. This will get me a VPS box at Linode, a GS box at MediaTemple, or a Shared Business or VPS 100 from ServerGrove. Aside from my a dev box at Dreamhost i use primarily for offsite subversion hosting these are the only hosts i ever use.

Of course i only have 1 or 2 Drupal deployments in the wild - most of my stuff is custom work in Symfony or Zend Framework.

Comment: I'm currently with godaddy shared & Virtual dedicated. On my shared account, I can push it to 128MB.

I had errors at 32MB, which is why I'm concerned...

Comment: I see. Ive never had issues at 50 - 128, but i also dont have that many modules installed beyond core - typically just one or two custom modules ive built specifically for that site, CCK, swftools and maybe a few other things - say like 8 - 10 tops. Of course i also dont run multi-site installs in production.

Comment: Wow, I admire your level of discipline. I have so many modules I use on almost every site I develop..(CCK, Views, LoginToboggan, Pathauto, admin_menu, user plus, ucreate, ImageCache to name a few). Not to mention one big module with all my hooks and functions.

Comment: I suppose its discipline in a sense, but i look at installing a module much like i do writing code from scratch - install/implement a whats needed to meet the functional requirements of a given project no more, no less. If the requirements change - then refactor or install additional modules.

Comment: We ended up going with Network Solutions VPS. I have concerns about scalability because their VPS tops at 1GB of ram. For a dedicated server, only running 1 low traffic site, this should be fine. The price was right at $40 per month.